# Ruler is missing in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, measurement, rulers

Ruler is missing in Android Studio v3.0. How can I make it shown?

[image]

Comment: I'm also finding out...

Comment: Well.... its 2020 and still looking for it
Any luck?